# If $A$ is diagonizable then $p(A)$ is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, polynomials, diagonalization

Show that if a matrix $A$ of size $n \times n$ is diagonalizable, then $p(A)$ is
diagonalizable for each polynomial $p$.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: Try the characteristic equation.. It might help

Comment: Hint: If $A$ is diagonalizable then we can write $A=XDX^{-1}$. Thus, $A^k = (XDX^{-1})^k = XDX^{-1}XDX^{-1}\dots XDX^{-1} = XD^k X^{-1}$. Hence, $A^k$ is diagonalizable. You think you can make it from here?

Answer (score 6):

We can write $p$ into this form:$$p(x) = a_mx^m + a_{m−1}x^{m−1} + · · · + a_1x + a_0$$
Now let $\Bbb v$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. 
Since $A^k\Bbb v = \lambda ^k\Bbb v$ for every $k$, we see that$$p(A)v = a_mA^m\Bbb v + a_{m−1}A^{m−1}\Bbb v + · · · + a_1A\Bbb v + a_0I\Bbb v
\\= a_mλ^m\Bbb v + a_{m−1}λ^{m−1}\Bbb v + · · · + a_1λ\Bbb v + a_0\Bbb v\\
= (a_mλ^m + a_{m−1}λ^{m−1} + · · · + a_1λ + a_0)v$$
Therefore, $p(A)\Bbb v = p(\lambda)\Bbb v$ which shows that $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $p(A)$, which means $p(A)$ is diagnolizable.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to consider eigenvalues or eigenvectors. You have:
$$ A = B^{-1} D B $$
with $D$ being a diagonal matrix. It follows that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$ A^n = (B^{-1}DB)\cdot(B^{-1}DB)\cdot\ldots\cdot(B^{-1}DB)= B^{-1} D^n B$$
holds, so for every polynomial $p\in\mathbb{R}[x]$
$$ p(A) = B^{-1} p(D) B$$
holds too. Since $p(D)$ is a diagonal matrix, the claim follows.

Comment: can we say P(A) is diogonalizabel then so A is?